# Unity problems with Play Game

Tags: unity-game-engine, google-play-games

I am having problems connecting to Play Games from Unity.
I keep on getting these messages in logcat:

```
Play Games callback indicates connection failure.
UI interaction required to connect to Google Play.
```

I have seen other places where they recommend checking the SHA-1 key set to see if it is set to the upload key.
I have double and triple checked and it is definitely right.

I also tried defining both of the keys to be sure but to no avail.

**Edit:**

**I checked the SHA-1 key that appears for the linked application within the Games console. There it appears with the signing of and not the upload one.**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After much hard work and searching I discovered the problem and am posting it here for others who may encounter it.

Simply said, if you intend to use Google Games Play in you Unity app DON'T use Google signing. ONLY sign with your own signing key.
Otherwise, it simply won't work.

In the end I just discarded the entry in the market (you can't opt-out Google signing once you have opted in) and made a new one.
Worked first time.

Comment: Can you please explicitly clarify what you mean by "ONLY sign with your own signing key"?

Answer (score 0):

First make sure that you've followed the setup here, [Setting Up Google Play Games Services](https://developers.google.com/games/services/console/enabling). It's involves quite a number of steps so bear with it.

Then follow the thread in this [github forum](https://github.com/playgameservices/play-games-plugin-for-unity/issues/1287):

> 1. on Game Services Turn on Saved Games
> 2. always make build with your keystore and password
> 3. add your mobile email id in game service's tester section

Comment: Did all those and it didn't help. In the end I added the google-signing certificate as well as the upload one and linked my app twice and suddenly it works.